# How do I configure Tomcat services in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I have created a Tomcat script inside the `/etc/init.d` directory which is

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.32
case $1 in
start)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
esac
exit 0
```

After this I am trying to add this into chkconfig which is as

```
[root@blanche init.d]# chkconfig --add tomcat
[root@blanche init.d]# chkconfig --level 234 tomcat on
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
[root@blanche init.d]:/etc/init.d$ chkconfig --add tomcat
insserv: warning: script 'K20acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'tomcat' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'failsafe-x' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'acpid' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dmesg' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevmonitor' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'ufw' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'module-init-tools' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-splash' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'gdm' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'rsyslog' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `wpa-ifupdown' overwrites defaults (empty).
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'console-setup' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-log' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0) of script `halt' overwrites defaults (empty).
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'mysql' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'atd' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-manager' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-mixer-save' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev-finish' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'avahi-daemon' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'procps' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'irqbalance' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-stop' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'anacron' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hostname' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock-save' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `networking' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `umountfs' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `umountnfs.sh' overwrites defaults (empty).
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface-security' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'apport' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (6) of script `reboot' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `umountroot' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (0 6) of script `sendsigs' overwrites defaults (empty).
insserv: There is a loop between service rsyslog and pulseaudio if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service pulseaudio at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service rsyslog at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service rsyslog and pulseaudio if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 2
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
/sbin/insserv failed, exit code 1
tomcat                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

Please suggest what to do for configuring a Tomcat server as a service.

Comment: Why would you use `chkconfig` on an Ubuntu system?

Comment: Because as referred from site http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_6_on_centos
It is mention their that it is the utility which is used start tomcat at boot time.

Comment: Why would you follow a guide on installing Tomcat on a CentOS system when you want to install Tomcat on an Ubuntu system?

Comment: I have two machines, 1 for testing purpose which has ubuntu install on it and another is my server machine on which cent os is installed. we need to test it first on ubuntu then move on to cent os.

Comment: Why would you have a testing machine which is a different configuration than your production machine?

Comment: Ok , just suggest me any solution for ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

So, the errors message points out to the missing LSB tags. I would try to add the tags manually to your custom init script. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          service_name
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remore_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 5
# Default-Stop:      2 3 5
# Short-Description: your_description
# Description:       start web server
### END INIT INFO
....
your code here
....
```

You can read more about the LSB tags and all possible directives [here](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

As soon as you have modified your script, run the following command:

```
insserv init_script_name
```